# Meraki VPN Traffic Capture

Tags: vpn, cisco, packet-capture, packet-sniffer

We have multiple offices interconnected via VPN using Meraki switches. I've been looking around and can't seem to find a way, but was thinking it's possible. Is it possible for me to put my desktop on one of the remote vpn'd subnets so I can monitor the traffic? We have one of our offices experiencing high traffic volume and we're looking for a comparison without having to remote into a local computer.

If this makes sense, is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean Meraki MXs? Your question makes it sound like the switches are what is providing your VPN service, which is not a feature of theirs.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have Meraki switches you can enable port mirroring (Configure -> Switch Settings) on the ports sending the vpn traffic and view it through your desktop and use something like Wireshark.

If you have Meraki APs or Appliances the monitoring is easier as packet capture and traffic analysis is all built in.